# XPath query to match attribute value against a set

Tags: xml, xpath

If I have for example the below xml

```
<root>
    <actors>
        <actor id="1">Christian Bale</actor>
        <actor id="2">Liam Neeson</actor>
        <actor id="3">Michael Caine</actor>
        <actor id="4">Sylvester Stallone</actor>
    </actors>
</root>
```

And a filter list with values (1,2,4). How can I write an XPath query that selects all actors that have an id with a value that is in the filter list?

I'm looking for a way to match attribute values against a list. I know you can do for instance `//root/actors/actor[@id<3]` to give me all actors that have an id value less than 3. Or `//root/actors/actor[@id=1 or @id=3]` to get actors with id 1 or 3. But this gets out of control quickly with longer lists. Is there an operator to compare against a list of values?

Comment: Obviously I can't search, that link answers my question

Comment: Have you stored all `@id` in variable or pass one by one in any application? @Andersson answer is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using XPath 2.0 you can use

```
/root/actors/actor[@id=(1, 2, 4)]
```

Comment: Even better than @Micha Wiedenmann's comment